# Divolte-collector with MAPR, Storm, Kafka and Cassandra

Tags: sockets

I am not sure if I can get help for this on here, but I thought it was worth a try.

I have 3 node cluster on AWS, I am running MAPR M3 , I installed Storm, Kafka and Divolte-collector and Cassandra. I would like try some of the clickstream examples and I am running into an issue with the [tcp-consumer example](https://github.com/divolte/divolte-examples/tree/master/tcp-kafka-consumer). Also being quite new to java and distributed processing I have some clarification questions. Again I am not quite sure where to post this because I feel like this is divolte-collector specific and I also have some gaps in my understanding of the javadoc concept and the building and running of jar files; but I figured someone could point me to some resources or help with some clarifications. I can't get the json string to appear in the console running netcat socket listening for clicks:

Divolte tcp-kafka-consumer example

Everything works until the netcat part step 7 and my knowledge gap is with step 6.

```
Step 1: install and configure Divolte Collector
```

Install works and hello world click collections is promising :-)

```
Step 2: download, unpack and run Kafka

# In one terminal session
cd kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/bin
./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties

# Leave Zookeeper running and in another terminal session, do:
cd kafka_2.10-0.8.1.1/bin
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

No erros plus tested kafka examples so seems to working as well

```
Step 3: start Divolte Collector

Go into the bin directory of your installation and run:

    cd divolte-collector-0.2/bin
    ./divolte-collector
```

Step 3 no hitch, can test default divole-collector test page

```
Step 4: host your Javadoc files

Setup a HTTP server that serves the Javadoc files that you generated or downloaded for the examples. If you have Python installed, you can use this:

    cd <your-javadoc-directory>
    python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Ok so I can reach the javadoc pages

```
    Step 5: listen on TCP port 1234
nc -kl 1234
Note: when using netcat (nc) as TCP server, make sure that you configure the Kafka consumer to use only 1 thread, because nc won't handle multiple incoming connections.
```

Tested netcat by opening port and sending messages so I figured I don't have any port issues on AWS.

```
Step 6: run the example

    cd divolte-examples/tcp-kafka-consumer
    mvn clean package
    java -jar target/tcp-kafka-consumer-*-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Note: for this to work, you need to have the avro-schema project installed into your local Maven repository.
```

I installed the avro-schema with mvn clean install in avro project that comes with the examples. as per instructions [here](https://github.com/divolte/divolte-examples/tree/master/avro-schema)

```
Step 7: click around and check that you see events being flushed to the console where you run netcat

When you click around the Javadoc pages, you console should show events in JSON format similar to this:
```

I don't see the clicks in my netcat window :(
Investigating the issue I viewed the console and network tabs using chrome developer tools it seems divolte is running, but I am not sure how to dig further. This is the console view. Any ideas or pointers?

Thanks anyways

```
 Initializing Divolte.
divolte.js:140 Divolte base URL detected http://ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:8290/
divolte.js:280 Divolte party/session/pageview identifiers ["0:i6i3g0jy:nxGMDVdU9~f1wF3RGqwmCKKICn4d1Sb9", "0:i6qx4rmi:IXc1i6Qcr17pespL5lIlQZql956XOqzk", "0:6ZIHf9BHzVt_vVNj76KFjKmknXJixquh"]
divolte.js:307 Module initialized. Object {partyId: "0:i6i3g0jy:nxGMDVdU9~f1wF3RGqwmCKKICn4d1Sb9", sessionId: "0:i6qx4rmi:IXc1i6Qcr17pespL5lIlQZql956XOqzk", pageViewId: "0:6ZIHf9BHzVt_vVNj76KFjKmknXJixquh", isNewPartyId: false, isFirstInSession: false…}
divolte.js:21 Signalling event: pageView 0:6ZIHf9BHzVt_vVNj76KFjKmknXJixquh0
allclasses-frame.html:9 GET http://ec2-x-x-x-x.us-west-x.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/resources/fonts/dejavu.css 
overview-summary.html:200 GET http://localhost:8290/divolte.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

(Intro: I work on Divolte Collector)

It seems that you are running the example on an AWS instance somewhere. If you are using the pre-packaged JavaDoc files that come with the examples, they have hard-coded the divolte location as http://localhost:8290/divolte.js. So if you are running somewhere other than localhost, you should probably create your own JavaDoc for the example, using the correct hostname for the Divolte Collector server.

You can do so using this command. Be sure to run it from the directory where you source tree is rooted. And of course change localhost for the hostname where you are running the collector.

```
javadoc -d YOUR_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY \
    -bottom '<script src="//localhost:8290/divolte.js" defer async></script>' \
    -subpackages .
```

As an alternative, you could also just try to run the examples locally first (possibly in a virtual machine, if you are on a Windows machine).

It doesn't seem there is anything MapR specific with the issue that you are seeing so far. The Kafka based examples and pipeline should work in any environment that has the required components installed. This doesn't touch MapR-FS or anything else MapR specific. Writing to the distributed filesystem is another story.

We don't compile Divolte Collector against MapR Hadoop currently, but incidentally I have given it a run on the MapR sandbox VM. When installing from the RPM distribution, create a /etc/divolte/divolte-env.sh with the following env var setting:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/share/divolte/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/share/divolte/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar:$(hadoop classpath)
```

Obviously this is a bit of a hack to get around classpath peculiarities and we hope to provide a distribution compiled against MapR that works out of the box in the future.

Also, you need Java 8 to run Divolte. If you install this from the [Oracle RPM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), add the proper JAVA_HOME to divolte-env.sh as well, e.g.:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
```

With these settings I'm able to run the server and collect Avro files on MapR FS, create a external Hive table on those files and run a query.